# Euler characteristic for a bounded chain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am stuck in proving certain formulas within Euler characteristics. Namely, in my next homework in homology, I was asked to prove the next two things:
$X(A.⊕B.) = X(A.) + X(B.)$

$X(A.⊗B.) X(A.)*X(B.)$
where $X$ stands for Euler characteristic and $A., B.$ stand for a bounded chain complexes of finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$.

The definition of $X$ is given by $X(C.)= ∑(-1)^n \cdot \dim(Cn)$.
As a matter of fact, I proved that $X(C.)=∑(-1)^n \cdot \dim(Hn(C.))$ which was also asked to prove, but I got stuck in these two. Is there any plausible hint?

Answer (score 0):

There's no hint, as you just have to unwind the definitions. Recall that

- the complex $A_\bullet \oplus B_\bullet$ has $A_n\oplus B_n$ in degree $n$;
- the complex $A_\bullet \otimes B_\bullet$ has $\bigoplus_{p+q=n} A_p\otimes_k B_q$ in degree $n$.

Then recall that

- $\dim (A_n\oplus B_n) = \dim A_n + \dim B_n$;
- $\dim (A_p\otimes_k B_q) = \dim A_p \cdot \dim B_q$.

Then use the definition $\chi (C_\bullet) := \sum_n (-1)^n \, \dim C_n$, and the identities
$$\chi (A_\bullet \oplus B_\bullet) = \chi (A_\bullet) + \chi (B_\bullet)\quad\text{and}\quad\chi (A_\bullet\otimes B_\bullet) = \chi (A_\bullet)\cdot \chi (B_\bullet)$$
should be immediate.

Comment: Yes, I get it now. Thanks a lot!